# GraphQL / Apollo Server Directives leading to schema error

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to add directives into our GraphQL API and am following this example, https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/creating-directives.html#Uppercasing-strings, however, I keep getting the server error (without the directive the server works!):

```
** Uncaught Error: Duplicate schema type name Integer **
    at home/node_modules/apollo-server-core/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/schemaVisitor.js:243:27
    at home/node_modules/apollo-server-core/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/schemaVisitor.js:527:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at each (home/node_modules/apollo-server-core/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/schemaVisitor.js:526:32)
    at heal (home/node_modules/apollo-server-core/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/schemaVisitor.js:234:13)
    at healSchema (home/node_modules/apollo-server-core/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/schemaVisitor.js:225:5)
    at Function.SchemaDirectiveVisitor.visitSchemaDirectives (home/node_modules/apollo-server-core/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/schemaVisitor.js:474:9)
    at Object.makeExecutableSchema (home/node_modules/apollo-server-core/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/makeExecutableSchema.js:54:48)
    at new ApolloServerBase (home/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer.js:142:43)
    at new ApolloServer (home/node_modules/apollo-server-express/dist/ApolloServer.js:44:1)
```

The schema is very large so I can't post it here, however, the schema type 'Integer' has not been duplicated. I've followed multiple different guides but keep running into this error.

We are using Apollo Server 2.1.0 & GraphQL 14.0.2

Server setup:

```
class error_extension extends GraphQLExtension {
  willSendResponse(o) {
    const { context, graphqlResponse } = o;

    context.add_additional_error_reporting(graphqlResponse.errors);

    return o;
  }
}


// Create (or import) a custom schema directive
class UpperCaseDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
    field.resolve = async function (...args) {
      const result = await resolve.apply(this, args);
      if (typeof result === 'string') {
        return result.toUpperCase();
      }
      return result;
    };
  }
}


// Server settings
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  schemaDirectives: {
    upper: UpperCaseDirective,
  },
  context: async ({ req, res }) => {
    // some auth logic here - removed for the purpose of this

    return {
      add_additional_error_reporting(errors) {
        if (!errors) return;

        errors = errors.map(item => {

          // add request data to the returned error
          if (`extensions` in item && item.extensions !== undefined)
            item.extensions.request_details = req.body;

          return item;
        });

        return errors;
      },
      req,
      res
    };
  },
  extensions: [() => new error_extension()],
  validationRules: [

    depthLimit(5),

    costAnalysis({ // GraphQL Query Cost 
      maximumCost: 100, // maximum cost of a single  query
      defaultCost: 1, // default cost of a field
      onComplete: (async request_cost => {
        // Callback function to retrieve the determined query cost. It will be invoked whether the query is rejected or not. 
        // This can be used for logging or to implement rate limiting (for example, to store the cost by session and define a max cost the user can have in a specific time).
        try { 
          cost_data = await helper.run_connector_cost_logic(request_cost);
        } catch (err) { throw err; }
      }),
      createError: (maximumCost, cost) => {
        // Function to create a custom error
        throw new ApolloError(`The maximum cost per request is ${maximumCost} however this request is greater than this limit, with a cost of ${cost}.`, `EXCEEDED_MAX_REQ_COST`);
      }
    })

  ],
  formatError: err => { 
    console.error(err); // eslint-disable-line
    return err; 
  },
  formatResponse: res => {
    res.extensions.cost = cost_data;

    // wipe the cost data for the next request
    cost_data = {};

    return res;
  },
  introspection: false,
  tracing: false,
  debug: false
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The example in the docs works as is, so I suspect it's something else. Would be great to see your schema, but at the very least you should include your full apollo-server configuration. That may provide some additional insight into what's going on.

Comment: FWIW, there's an issue [here](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/issues/716) but it looks like it didn't get much traction.

Comment: @DanielRearden thanks for chiming in again - now added the server setup to the question. I'll put a comment on that issue too. Thanks!

Comment: I've stripped the server setup to the bare minimum (typeDefs, resolvers & schemaDirectives) and still hit the same problem. I agree that logic says it is unlikely it is the example however the part that particularly confuses me is that we have no type called 'Integer' in the schema - we have one scalar called 'Integer' but that is it... also odd that it works fine when there are no directives

Comment: If you have a custom scalar called `Integer` then that's what your error is referring to. Scalars are still types. The error is coming from `graphql-tools` (look [here](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/blob/master/src/schemaVisitor.ts#L323)). That validation logic doesn't get called unless you include directives. Could be a bug with graphql-tools. Could be an issue with the way you're setting the custom scalars.

Comment: Would be curious to know how you're including and using the custom scalars in your typeDefs

Comment: @DanielRearden Thanks for the info RE why the error is only now showing up. So in the custom scalars we basically have some logic that builds multiple Integer type scalars i.e. with different min and max values & names although there was a dodgy if statement 'if (min_number)', so when we pass in a min number of 0 the code wasn't running  when it should have been and wasn't dynamically changing the name hence the duplicate name error. Really, really appreciate all your help, could have spent ages hunting for that without your pearls of wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with our Scalars which are generated using JS logic however one statement was flawed leading to multiple Scalars with the same name value.

For anyone else, as @Daniel Rearden said in the comments "The error is coming from graphql-tools. That validation logic doesn't get called unless you include directives" hence why the error has only just showen up i.e. it was nothing related to directives.